# cmath Errors when using FLTK

Tags: c++, build-process, fltk, cmath

For some reason, whenever I add the FLTK directory to my include path, I get a bunch of errors from *cmath*.  I am using GCC version 4.2.  Here is a sample program and the build output:

*main.cpp*

```
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project CMath Test ****

make -k all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/include/FL -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o"main.o" "../main.cpp"
In file included from ../main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:100: error: ‘::acos’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:116: error: ‘::asin’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:132: error: ‘::atan’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:148: error: ‘::atan2’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:165: error: ‘::ceil’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:181: error: ‘::cos’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:197: error: ‘::cosh’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:213: error: ‘::exp’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:229: error: ‘::fabs’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:245: error: ‘::floor’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:261: error: ‘::fmod’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:271: error: ‘::frexp’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:287: error: ‘::ldexp’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:303: error: ‘::log’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:319: error: ‘::log10’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:335: error: ‘::modf’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:354: error: ‘::pow’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:376: error: ‘::sin’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:392: error: ‘::sinh’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:408: error: ‘::sqrt’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:424: error: ‘::tan’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.2/cmath:440: error: ‘::tanh’ has not been declared
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
make: Target `all' not remade because of errors.
Build complete for project CMath Test
```

---

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,treelang --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --enable-nls --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2 --program-suffix=-4.2 --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --enable-mpfr --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.3 (Ubuntu 4.2.3-2ubuntu7)
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Post the output of "g++ -v" on your system.

Comment: It looks like math.h is missing or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure speculation, but is there a 'math.h' header in `/usr/include/FL` by any chance?  Or is there some other header in there that is included by `cmath`?

*[...a little time passes...]*

Still speculation, but given the comment "Yes, there is - what's going on?", I will speculate that there is no 'math.h' header in /usr/include - because if there was GCC (G++) would normally pick up  from the same place as ''.  So, I would check the installed software - headers under /usr/include - for sanity.

*[...a little more time passes...]*

Ah, well...it seems that the problem is that there are two `math.h` headers, and the compiler is picking the wrong one.

There are a couple of tricks you can try.  First, perhaps, is to check the documentation of FLTK: are you supposed to use `<FL/header.h>` or just `<header.h>` to access its headers?  If you are supposed to use the version with the sub-directory, then you don't need to add `-I/usr/include/FL` to the compilation command line; the references to `<FL/header.h>` will be handled automatically (by looking for `/usr/include/FL/header.h` when scanning `/usr/include` - just like `<sys/types.h>` is found under `/usr/include`).

If that isn't part of the answer, then you can try using the flags:

```
-I/usr/include -I/usr/include/FL
```

This says "search `/usr/include` before searching `/usr/include/FL` (and then search `/usr/include` again after searching `/usr/include/FL`)".  That should solve the immediate problem - however it might cause trouble with whatever is supposed to include `/usr/include/FL/math.h`.  This is definitely not as reliable as the first option.

Comment: Yes, there is!  What's going on?

Comment: Okay, thanks to you, I figured it out.  There is a math.h in my /usr/include directory, but the one in /usr/include/FL is taking precedence.  I can remove the math.h in /usr/include/FL, which solves the problem, but is there any way to tell the compiler explicitly which math.h to use?

Comment: Ah!  Yes, it was my fault.  I'm supposed to do '#include <FL/Fl.H>' and so on.  Thus, my include path should only include /usr/include (Ha-ha).  Thanks for the help.  That was very subtle to me.  I hope I can diagnose this sort of problem in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. It was caused by an inadvertent creation of a `math.h` in the include path by Qt Creator creating a math subpackage for me the project that hid the `math.h` file. The I found it was to simply do a `find / -name math.h`. Sure it may take a while, but it gets them all.

Answer (score 0):

Scott, add `-lm` to the list of linker flags there, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use Qt Creator 3.3.0 and got the same problem

It's funny that I have solved it by moving the line

**#include < cmath>**

to the top line before other #includes

It solves my problems!!!